# HIde a div with a PHP echo statement with CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I am using the CSS **display:none** to hide divs in my html code.  It works fine for divs that hold general html content and hides the content.

However, if the div happens to hold a PHP echo statement it does not hide the contents.

**HTML**

```
<span class="paginationFull"><?php echo $paginationCtrls;?></span>
<span class="paginationMini"><?php echo $paginationCtrlsMob;?></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.paginationFull{display:none}
```

Essentially, I am looking to show full pagination controls if in desktop and mini pagination controls if 320px - 420px.  I thought that CSS display:none would be a nice easy way to do this.  Does anyone, know how to accomplish this? Thanks for any help. Andy ;-)

Comment: Those are `span` tags and not `div` tags, but php is parsed before html / css so your css should be applied to the content of the echo's regardless if it comes from php or not. - Do you have other classes applied that might interfere?

Comment: Maybe you have error on `.css` file, or maybe you didn't include `.css` file to page `header`

Comment: Inspect your HTML source code, in the browser, does it look like you expect?

Comment: Or maybe there's bad HTML in `$pageinationCtrls`. Open your browser's developer console to examine the DOM and CSS.

Comment: I really can't tell what you logic is but see this <span class="paginationMini"  <?php if(---){echo 'style="display:none"'; }else { ... }?>><?php echo $paginationCtrlsMob;?></span>. This lets you hide the span if a criteria is met. Or better still, try js

Comment: `.paginationFull{display:none}` works well for me anyway. i think you should focus on debugging. and you can use `tab-pane` from `bootstrap` with some jquery for simple pagination

Comment: I actually had it working more or less, just forgot to follow the naming convention down the page...opps! Ah well, working now, thanks for the suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some good `php` libraries that can detect whether the user is on their phone or on a desktop. You can then use this to control which nav is used.

Example using http://mobiledetect.net/

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$md = new Mobile_Detect();

if($md->isMobile()){
    echo '<span class="paginationMini">' . $paginationCtrlsMob . '</span>';
}else{
    echo '<span class="paginationFull">' . $paginationCtrls . '</span>';
}
```

`display:none` should work regardless of whether you have an echo statement inside the `<span>` tag. The only explanation as to why its not working in your case is if the php variables contain tags that aren't properly closed.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the example, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't make a difference what is inside the span tag except you have some sort of HTML within span that "destroys" the DOM, so the HTML isn't valid anymore.

Besides that, you should make use of CSS media queries:

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries#device-width